# How to scroll horizontally InteractiveViewer with overflowed widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am pretty new to flutter. I am trying to replicate app that I have already made using only Android Views and Java.

So what I am trying to do is create stack of hidable/showable map layers (roads, marks, etc.). I want it to be zoomable and expanded to the height of the screen. Layers are 1:1 so it will overflow the screen width. That is intended.

So I found out that **InteractiveViewer** allows me to zoom. As a child I created **Stack** (with *StackFit.expand* parameter) of **SvgPicture.asset**s (I am using svg files). Problem is, the InteractiveViewer allows me to zoom only the visible part of the Stack and do not allow me to scroll horizontally to the edges of the Stack.

What should I change to be able to zoom it correctly or scroll to the edges? I was trying to play with **SingleChildScrollView**, **OverflowBox** or **InteractiveViewer**'s *isConstrained* parameter, but no success. Most of the times, the Stack of layers just disappeared. I'm willing to drop the zooming for at least scrolling to left and right. I was playing with **SingleChildScrollView** that wrapped **Stack** but no success either.

In the picture below there is a sketch of what it looks like. **Orange** part is header, rectangle with **red** border is the overflowed Stack with layers and rectangle with **blue** border is the area I can zoom within.

Image:

[image]

Code is here:

```
      Container(
        color: Color(Values.colorBodyMap),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: AutoSizeText( ... )
               )
             )
          ]),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                  child: Stack(
                         fit: StackFit.expand,
                         children: [for ( ... ) SvgPicture.asset(s, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)],
          )))
      ]))
```

Comment: can you please use SingleScrollView and share your result ?

Comment: Well, when I use SingleChildScrollView -> Stack -> *layers*, it disappears. Only visible is the header and background set to the base Container (colorBodyMap). However, if I wrap the ScrollView with SizedBox with width set, it works, but I do not want this. I want width to be dynamic, based on height (cause 1:1 ratio) remaining in the Column.